# is it possible in java to create a class that have all fields as observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, android-livedata

I am currently learning reactive programming in Java (for Android).

I used Livedata to listen to the changes in a field .

But I am having a problem . Is it possible to trigger a listener each and every time when a fields in the model class got updated ?

That is ,

- When a class field updated , a listener have to be triggered
- That listener have to return the updated object

Ok. Let me explain in detail

**Scenario** 
Imagine some Model classes

```
class Student 
{
String name ;
int age;
int rollno;
Sports sports ;
}


class Sports 
{
 String sportName;
 int score;
}
```

Now this is my need .

> When I update a field in the Student class' object , then a listener
>   have to be triggered the return the updated object of the Student
>   class

For instance

if I update the name as `stdobj.name = "Lords"`  , then a listener have to be triggered , that return the updated object like this

```
....
public void onUpdated (Student student)
{
...
}
```

if I changed age field as `stdobj.age = 25`  , then a listener have to be triggered , that return the updated object

**Note**
The listener also have to be triggered when the sport object also updated like 
`stdobj.sports = new Sports (....)`.

**My Previous Works**

I used `Observable interface and BaseObservable` .

> but I need to add `notifypropertychaged(<field_name>)` for each and
>   every variable .

What if the model class had 100 variable. Adding 100 `notifypropertychaged(<field_name>)` is a pain.

The same thing happened with `MutableLiveData`. I had to convert all fields to livedata object and also need to create a separate observers for these livedata objects

> So above solution is not prefect for me . I need something that
>   automatically observe all fields by a single time implementation .

**Some thing like these:**

```
class Student extends FieldsObserver<Student> 
{
...
...

@Override
public void onFieldChanged (Student student)
{
...
...
}
```

OR like this

```
FieldChangedObserver observer = ...;

observer.observe(stdobj, new OnFieldChangedListener() 
  {
    public void onFieldChanged (Student student)
       {
       ....
       }
  });
```

---

This is my need . Please tell solution

Comment: Check out `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @akarnokd It's for JS .. I want for java

Comment: Why do you think that? This says [BehaviorSubject.java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.java). Java!